# How to change the time format in datepicker?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use Angular Material and its Datepicker component. And I have a problem when I make a report. All dates are displayed in this way.

> Fri Jan 25 2019 00:00:00 GMT 0500 (Ekaterinburg, standard time)

And I need the dates in the report to be in this format `25.01.2019`

I tried not to use the datepicker component, and all dates are displayed normally, but I don’t want to work without this component.

How can fix this?

ts:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { Report } from "../../../../shared/interfaces";

import * as _moment from 'moment';
const moment = _moment;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-report',
  templateUrl: './report.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./report.component.scss']
})

export class ReportComponent {

  selectedReport: Report
  report_url: string = 'http://localhost:3000' + '/reports/svod'
  selectedDate: string = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ReportComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA)
    public data: any
  ) { 
    this.selectedReport = new Report()
  }

  onSelectDate(event): void {
    this.selectedReport = new Report()
    this.selectedDate = event
  }

}
```

html:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [ngModel]="selectedDate" [matDatepicker]="dp" (ngModelChange)="onSelectDate($event)" >
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dp></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: solved the problem himself

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to format date:

```
  onSelectDate(event): void {
    this.selectedReport = new Report()
    this.selectedDate = formatDate(event, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'en-US') // Try to convert here
  }
```

Comment: After that, I can not select dates that I do not have in the database

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#setting-the-locale-code), you need to provide alocale to work with the best format. So for you, it should be something like this:

---

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-report',
  templateUrl: './report.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./report.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MyDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: CUSTOM_DATE_FORMAT },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: "**YOUR LOCALE**" }
  ]
})
```

---

```
export const CUSTOM_DATE_FORMAT: MatDateFormats = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};
```

---

Comment: I did this, too, but a set of numbers is displayed in my report in the place of the date (1548356400000)

Comment: @user10966440 maybe try to do: this.selectedDate = new Date(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));